# Saving and renaming multiple files as PDF without asking for location at the same time

Tags: vba, pdf-generation, ms-word, file-rename, export-to-pdf

I have three word doc files and I want to rename them with `Now()` date. Three files are as

**1.** EMEA.doc   **--rename->** EMEA 083117.doc **-convert->** EMEA 082317.PDF

**2.** CEEMEA.doc **--rename->** CEEMEA 083117.doc **-convert->** CEEMEA 082317.PDF

**3.** LATAM.doc  **--rename->** LATAM 083117.doc **-convert->** LATAM 082317.PDF

I need to `ExportAsFixedFormat`(PDF) these `.Doc` files. Following code do the job for `ActiveDocument` only. I want to save files in specific location without VBA asking for location.

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\LATAM.pdf", ExportFormat _
    :=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why don't you just open them one by one in the code and do the same for all of them? Or use a loop?

Comment: @vacip it take time to open and print and i want to save it. as files in question are just example there are lot of files to rename and convert.

Comment: why don't you do `EMEA.doc  -convert-> EMEA 082317.PDF` ?

Comment: @jsotola actually I need both files with date `EMEA 082317.doc` and `EMEA 082317.pdf`, and file without date `EMEA.doc` is no use for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create [UserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcTwa.png) for three files and copy the code (Given below) in `PDF_Click`.

code will Open all three of them one by one  and do `SAVEAS` with `Now()` date and create **PDF** for check-marked files using `For loop`.

```
Private Sub PDF_Click()

Dim d As String

Finalize.hide
Dim C As MSForms.Control
For Each C In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(C) = "CheckBox" Then
    If C.Value = True Then
    If C.Caption = "Select All" Then
    Else

VD = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\"

Documents.Open FileName:=VD & C.Caption & ".doc"

d = Format(Now(), "mmddyy")
f = VD & Ctl.Caption & " " & d
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 f & ".doc"

ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        f & ".pdf", ExportFormat _
        :=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, TO:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

ActiveDocument.Close

    End If
    End If
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

This answer is open for critics, To improve.

Answer (score 3):

General direction:

1. You need to tell the program which files you want to manipulate (e.g. "[all word files in folder x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526577/loop-through-all-word-files-in-directory)")
2. You seem to already have a rule for renaming (file name & " " & date), just loop through all files in question; a [batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013145/windows-batch-file-rename) might be a good alternative solution to vba for renaming files
3. [Open and save each document to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042575/multiple-word-doc-to-pdf-convert) (can be done in background, no need to actually open the document)

**Note**: You never actually "convert" a word file, only save an additional (PDF) file. To make it look like a "conversion", you need to save the PDF in the same location and delete the original word file.

If you need help with a specifc problem in your program, update your post with the lines of code in question along with a descritpion of the error/wrong behaviour, desired behaviour and what you have tried so far to fix it.